# How to run application on android wearable device which is develop in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, wear-os

I want to run an application which is developed in Eclipse on an android wearable device. I have gone through different links and performed the required steps but no success. Please help me out.
Links which I have refer are as follows:

1) https://medium.com/@tangtungai/how-to-develop-and-package-android-wear-app-using-eclipse-ef1b34126a5d

2) http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html#AssetCompression

Comment: So what's your problem. What doesn't work? Basically the medium-link you've posted describes nearly everything.

Comment: Yes reverse, I have resolve it.During implementation i am forgot to make Manifest entry for metadata tag.